# Trouble filling a Python tkinter/turtle window with squares

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas

I'm having trouble with getting the `turtle.begin_fill()` / `turtle.end_fill()` commands to work in a tkinter window. I want to have the program draw a bunch of coloured cells onto the screen in a 64x32 grid. This the whole code to set up the window and draw however it simply doesn't do anything after setting up a window:

```
import turtle as tu
import tkinter as tk

axis = []
num = -512

for i in range(0,64):
    axis.append(num)
    num = num + 16

def drawworld(*args):
    for i in range(0,64):
        for j in range(0,32):
            tu.goto(axis[i],axis[j]+256)
            tu.pd()
            tu.color=("#ffff00")
            tu.begin_fill()
            for k in range(0,4):
                tu.fd(16)
                tu.lt(90)
            tu.end_fill()
            tu.pu()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("game")
root.resizable(False, False)
canvas = tk.Canvas(master = root, width = 1024, height = 512)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10)
tu = tu.RawTurtle(canvas)
tu.speed(50)
tu.pu()
tu.ht()

drawworld()

root.mainloop()
```

however, if I were to comment out the fill lines, the code works perfectly (without colouring the boxes) which means there must be something wrong with:

```
tu.color=("#ffff00")
tu.begin_fill()
for k in range(0,4):
    tu.fd(16)
    tu.lt(90)
tu.end_fill()
tu.pu()
```

I've looked up the documentation and this should be perfect syntax. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is this line:

```
tu.color=("#ffff00")
```

which probably should be:

```
tu.color("#ffff00")
```

to set the color, you don't assign to the turtle's color property but rather invoke the turtle's `.color()` method.  Your code with this change and some other cleanup:

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import RawTurtle

axis = []
num = -512

for _ in range(64):
    axis.append(num)
    num += 16

def drawworld():
    for i in range(64):
        for j in range(32):
            tu.goto(axis[i], axis[j] + 256)
            tu.pendown()
            tu.color("#ffff00")
            tu.begin_fill()
            for _ in range(4):
                tu.forward(16)
                tu.left(90)
            tu.end_fill()
            tu.penup()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("game")
root.resizable(False, False)

canvas = tk.Canvas(master=root, width=1024, height=512)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10)

tu = RawTurtle(canvas)
tu.speed('fastest')
tu.hideturtle()
tu.penup()

drawworld()

root.mainloop()
```

However, this is a painfully slow way to go about this. There are faster ways, here's one that uses stamping to speed up the process:

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import RawTurtle
from random import random

CUBE_SIZE = 16
CURSOR_SIZE = 20
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1024, 512

axis = []
num = -HEIGHT

for _ in range(WIDTH // CUBE_SIZE):
    axis.append(num)
    num += CUBE_SIZE

def drawworld():
    for i in range(WIDTH // CUBE_SIZE):
        tu.goto(axis[i] + CUBE_SIZE // 2, axis[0] + HEIGHT // 2 + CUBE_SIZE // 2)

        for j in range(HEIGHT // CUBE_SIZE):
            tu.color(random(), random(), random())
            tu.stamp()
            tu.forward(CUBE_SIZE)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("game")
root.resizable(False, False)

canvas = tk.Canvas(master=root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10)

tu = RawTurtle(canvas)
tu.shape('square')
tu.shapesize(CUBE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
tu.speed('fastest')
tu.hideturtle()
tu.setheading(90)
tu.penup()

drawworld()

root.mainloop()
```